# Execute in fabric run('hg pull')

Tags: python, django, deployment, mercurial, fabric

I'm developing some Django application on Windows host computer. I've created fabfile with tasks. In one of my steps I execute something like that:

```
local("hg pull")
local("hg update")
```

and it works properly.

In other task I try to execute on remote machine something similar:

```
run("hg pull")
```

but after that I get error:

```
[XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] run: hg pull
Exception in thread Thread-6:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\threading.py", line 808, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Grzegorz\VirtualEnvs\Dummy\lib\site-packages\paramiko\agent.py", line 116, in run
    self._communicate()
  File "C:\Users\Grzegorz\VirtualEnvs\Dummy\lib\site-packages\paramiko\agent.py", line 122, in _communicate
    import fcntl
ImportError: No module named fcntl
```

Do you have any advices how can I pull and updated changes from my mercurial repository?

Comment: Could you show what `fabric` and `paramiko` versions are you using?

Comment: @Grzegorz: Is the exception nice in blue? ;)

Comment: @alecxe: Fabric 1.7.0 and paramiko 1.11.0 (on local and remote machine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, now it works. I didn't change anything in my virtual environments but set proper path to my  source code from repository and call something like that:

```
run('hg pull https://usr:pwd@bitbucket.org/account/myproject')
```

Answer (score 0):

This was failing with the same error for me, until I set:

```
fabric.api.env.forward_agent = False
```

I originally had a ssh:// target as the default repo, so I guess this the remote ssh-agent not liking my identity (but liking the remote user's better than the one I was trying to forward).

Switching to the https:// target, as you did, solves this as well by side-stepping the ssh identities.